# Can't unpickle a list in windows

Tags: python, windows, python-2.7, pickle

I've gone through every tutorial and stackexchange question I could and it seems that I'm doing everything right, but I cannot unpickle anything.  I'm using windows 7 and coding using python 2.7.9.  The code shown is below.

```
import pickle

purple = open("E://Users//Purple//Desktop//test_pickle.pkl",'wb')
my_list = ["a", 6, "purple"]
pickle.dump(my_list, purple,0)
purple.close()
print my_list

a = open("E://Users//Purple//Desktop//test_pickle.pkl",'rb')

try:
    b = pickle.load(a)
    print b
except EOFError:
    print "EOFerror"

a.close()
```

Every time I run the code, I get an EOFerror.

Edit: Fixed parenthesis.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It should be `purple.close()`, you're missing parentheses :-).

Comment: I just ran it again, and the results are still the same